# Class not being created

Tags: python, django, class

I'm trying to create a Menu class that is comprised of a list of dishes coming from the Dish class. When a Restaurant is created, I want to also create the Menu which initially has no Dishes to start off. When I run the code though, model_create.py, I'm getting an error that Menu is not created which halts everything.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    open_time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    close_time = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cook_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fresh_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
    #description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serve = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Menu(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
    last_served = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default = None)


#model_create.py
from ..models import User, Restaurant, Dish, Menu
def create_restaurant():
    restaurant = Restaurant()
    restaurant.save()
    create_menu(restaurant.id)
    return restaurant.id

def create_menu(res_id):
    menu = Menu(restaurant_id = res_id) #restaurant_id var name in database
    menu.save()
    return
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm doing this as a Django website, so the only real relevant traceback information I have is that menu = Menu(restaurant_id = res_id) fails to create a new Menu class. Which in turn causes the whole thing to fail.

Comment: Have you tried `menu = Menu(restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=res_id))`?, Or passing  restaurant object  instead of  id?

Comment: You have declared `dish` as a foreign key object in your Menu model class.  This means that each Menu object can have at most 1 dish associated with it.  It may help you to read the documentation about Django models and relationships https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#relationships